# Validating file names before being pushed to GIT repository to make sure they are ASCII only

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a requirement where I need to validate if the file names that are pushed to the Git repository are ASCII only before they end up in the repository.

So far server side hooks are not an option as I do not have access to the GitLab server that is hosting the repository.

I have tried client side hooks and there is actually a sample script it the .git\hooks that does ASCII validation and I have tested it and it works well, but it requires the hook script to be manually copied by the user into this directory. The problem is if the user forgets to copy the script into the hooks directory and push invalid files to the repository it is going to cause issues down the line.

Does anyone know what other options exist that could solve this requirement?

**UPDATE #1:**

In the end what I have done was to modify my .gitlab-ci.yaml to look for Non-Ascii, Non-Printable characters in the file and folder names.
If it found any then I failed the pipeline.

`- check=$(find . -print0 | perl -n0e 'chomp; print $_, "\n" if /[[:^ascii:][:cntrl:]]/' | wc -c)
 - > 
      if [ $check != 0 ]
       then
           echo "Found Non-ASCII OR Non-Printable file or directory names."
           find . -print0 | perl -n0e 'chomp; print $_, "\n" if /[[:^ascii:][:cntrl:]]/'
        exit 1
      fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @jthill you cannot do this with git hook.
I am aligned with his answer, perhaps you are admin of the repo but not the server.

A solution is to protect the merge request with cicd, you can create a `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file. Create a file linter and mark the step failed is a file is not at your standard.

This is not preventing to create file on commit, but protect your main banches

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to control what gets pushed to a repository, you're going to need admin access to it because control over what happens in a repository is quite simply the definition of administrative authority.

So presumably if you don't have that access to the hosted repository, you don't own it. It's not yours. And if whoever's imposing this requirement on you doesn't have that access within their gift, they don't own it either. I require you to deliver me all the gold in Fort Knox. Now you have another and every bit as sensible requirement.